# Variables created in initialiser not available in test, but from console(Ruby on Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I've created a library I want to initialize once when the app starts.
So I've written an initializer that does this. And this seam to work when I start rails console, but `@push_notifications` is not available from my tests. How can that be?

**app/models/post.rb**

```
class Post < ApplicationRecord
  after_save :send_notifications
```

**spec/models/post_spec.rb**

```
require "rails_helper"

RSpec.describe Post, type: :model do
  before(:each) do
    @user = Fabricate(:user)
    @post = Fabricate(:post, user: @user)
  end

  it "is valid from the fabric" do
    expect(@post).to be_valid
  end
```

**lib/push_notifications.rb**

```
class PushNotifications
  def initialize
    puts "PushNotifications#initialize"
    FCM.new(ENV["FCM_SERVER_KEY"])
  end

  def new_post_in_group(post:)
    # [cut...]
  end
```

**config/initializers/PushNotifications.rb**

```
require "#{Rails.root}/lib/push_notifications"

puts "initialize PushNotifications"
@push_notifications ||= PushNotifications.new
```

**$ rails console**

```
initialize PushNotifications
PushNotifications#initialize


[1] pry(main)> @push_notifications
=> #<PushNotifications:0x00007fa22650b250>
```

**running tests**

```
rspec spec/models/post_spec.rb
initialize PushNotifications
PushNotifications#initialize

Post
  is valid from the fabric (FAILED - 1)

Failures:

  1) Post is valid from the fabric
     Failure/Error: @push_notifications.new_post_in_group(post: self)

     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `new_post_in_group' for nil:NilClass
     # ./app/models/post.rb:85:in `send_notifications'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`@push_notifications` is an instance variable, so it's instance context-dependent, you should assign it to a constant:

```
PUSH_NOTIFICATIONS = PushNotifications.new
```

Comment: Thanks, that was it! :-)

Answer (score 0):

Your Question is incomplete, please include a codesnippet of the spec that fails (the output of rspec is not very helpful here).

In Pry you are often "inside" objects, meaning you can access data which is not visible from the outside. For access from outside you might need an `attr_reader :push_notifications` in the respective class.

Setting instance variables in the initializer is probably not what you want. Where should your `@push_notifications` object be available from? Is it something that you need in your controllers? Then you should initialize - and store - it there (in a specific controller or if needed everywhere in an `ApplicationController < ActiveRecord::Base` class from which every other controller inherits.
Is it something you need in a special model (like in `Post`) then define it over there.

Also is it correct that your `PushNotification` class creates a `FCM` object but does not store a reference to it? What is `FCM` supposed to do?